# Rails: Get hostname in an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hostname, initializer

I'm using Sorcery for Authentication, and I need to setup third party authentication in its initializer.

The initializer has a line that looks like this:

```
config.twitter.callback_url "http://example.dev/auth/callback?provider=twitter"
```

...where `example.dev` is the hostname when I'm using Pow in local development. This needs to be `example.com` if the app is in production, or `staging.example.com` if it's in staging, etc.

I would like to set this line to be something like this:

```
config.twitter.callback_url "#{Rails.hostname}/auth/callback?provider=twitter"
```

... but `request.host` is the only method I know of that knows that and it's only available at the controller level.

I can use a conditional test and manually setup a hostname for each environment, but as I test on different local and staging environments it would be great to just be able to set this programatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
`hostname`
```

That uses the Unix "hostname" utility, and it returns a string.

Comment: with the backticks? as in `config.twitter.callback_url "#{\`hostname\`}/..."` ?

Comment: Right, yes, backticks.  You can test it pretty easily with the Rails console.  Just go into the console and type "hostname" with the backticks to see what it will return.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the hostname via [`Socket.gethostname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-gethostname) which is part of the Ruby Standard Library.