# Get domain URL in Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a facebook auth callback in the `devise.rb` initializer, and want to set the domain as the current domain.

`callback_url: "what-goes-here/auth/facebook/callback"`

And I want this to dynamically be

`localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback` or
`example.com/auth/facebook/callback`

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764352/rails-get-hostname-in-an-initializer), and tried `#{'hostname'}`, which in dev it puts `My-Macbook-Air` instead of `localhost:3000`, and in production it gives a long string of letters and numbers instead of `example.com`

I also tried `Socket.gethostname` but this just gives a long string of letters and numbers.

How can I get the domain URL in a Rails initializer? Thanks!!